# ListView with EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

`enter code here`I have a `ListView` that have a different Layout XML for each cell,this is how i set it up:

```
    this.setContentView(R.layout.item_view);

    ListView m_ListView = this.getListView();
    m_ListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    m_ListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    m_ListView.setCacheColorHint(0x00000000);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ArrayList<View> views=new ArrayList<View>();
    e = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_first, null);

    views.add(e);

    r = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_second, null);

    views.add(r);

    t = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_third, null);

    views.add(t);

    mAdapter = new SillyAdapter(views);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now in one of the Layout i have 3 `EditText` ,the first is selected and when i press him the keyboard in the device is not opened, and when i pressed the two others the first one is still selected,this is how the xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:lines="2" 
        android:textColor="@color/Red" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:hint="Name" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/> <requestFocus />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Telephone" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp">


        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:textColor="@color/Red" android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:gravity="center" android:hint="E-Mail" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_req"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="@color/Red" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/hazmana" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why the keyboard in the device is not popup?

## Edit

Theis is SillyAdapter :

```
class SillyAdapter extends SackOfViewsAdapter {
    public SillyAdapter(List<View> views) {
      super(views);
    }

    protected View newView(int position, ViewGroup parent) {
      TextView txt=new TextView(Catalog.this);
      return(txt);
    }
}
```

and `Catalog` is the main Class

Comment: Nice to meet you and your code. And what is the question, please?

Comment: can you show what you have in this Class `SillyAdapter` where you pass `ArrayList` with `View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi. My assumption is that the problem lay in the following code:

```
m_ListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Try to remove that line or change `false` to `true`

Comment: yep it was this, i change it to true